# json representation for d3 force directed networks

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to make a network visualisation of RISK. You can view it with the required code at http://bl.ocks.org/4683850.

The visualisation works but it required a lot of manual labor. I manually adapted the json file such that the connections were of the following shape:

```
{
    "source": 1,
    "target": 0,
    "value": 5
}
```

What would one need to do to the d3 code such that a connection is determined by the names of the nodes? The input would then be:

```
{
    "source": "WesternAustralia",
    "target": "NewGuinea",
    "value": 5
}
```

Whenever I try that I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The D3 docs provide an explanation of how links work:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-links

In short, the array of links can either contain indices for `source` and `target`, which get remapped to objects from `nodes`, or they contain the references to the objects from `nodes` themselves. You need to remap your links' `source` and `target` to the objects from `nodes`.

Assuming your `source` and `target` properties are using names as shown in your second example above, you can add the follow snippet to the beginning of your `d3.json` callback to do the remapping:

```
    var nodeMap = {};
    graph.nodes.forEach(function(x) { nodeMap[x.name] = x; });
    graph.links = graph.links.map(function(x) {
      return {
        source: nodeMap[x.source],
        target: nodeMap[x.target],
        value: x.value
      };
    });
```

Comment: Nice solution! That helped me out.